# How to quickly search big text line separated data file?

Tags: csv, command-line, solr, indexing

I've got a big datafile (>= 300M, csv), and want to query data and return line from it.

I can use this method:

```
grep pattern data.csv
```

But it is very slow. I need query several patterns, so maybe index this file is a good solution .

Is there any good commandline tool can do this job?

I know there are:

- idutils: query is fast, but return result need to access the datafile make it slow.
- solr: not that easy to use.

Comment: If you really want to have a go, Hadoop (and its derivative tools) is designed for this, albeit on a much larger scale. Principles should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a lot specifics from your question that would make it easier to help you. For instance, the fields in your CSV, the pattern(s) you typically search upon, if you are searching against the same data set each time, and search frequency. Assuming you need to search against the same data set in ways not supported by grep and/or idutils, Solr makes sense. For instance if you want to do searching that can return partial matches Solr makes this much easier.

While not a command line solution, [standing up Solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Installing+Solr) and [loading it with CSV](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV) is a straightforward activity. Depending on the size in bytes of your CSV it make not require any tuning. The hard work is [defining a Solr schema.xml definition](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) that indexes your data in a way that supports your various search requirements. In your particular case it sounds like you want to do have some tokenization and perhaps stemming done to your searchable fields as you are already looking to do pattern matching. But that really depends on your specific search needs.